# Redirect user after authorization where user previously clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

Somehow I came to a problem of thinking of how to make that if the person clicks on a link, it should be redirected to sign-in page if not authorized and to that page if authorized. This sounds easy, but the problem is that I want to make that if the user redirected to one page where it should be authorized, the user authorizes and redirect to the same page as he clicked.

For now, I have a protected route that looks like this: (I have `fromPath` argument for next redirection but that does not work for me.)

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
  isAllowed,
  redirectPath = "/sign-in",
  fromPath = null,
  children,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  if (fromPath) dispatch(setURLPath(fromPath));


  if (!isAllowed) {
    return <Navigate to={fromPath} replace />;
  }
  return children ? children : <Outlet />;
};
```

And here how it looks from the `App.js` side:

```
<Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Routes>
          <Route
            path='/'
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute
                isAllowed={roleLevel > 0}
              />
            }
          >
            <Route path='bookings' element={<BookingsPage />} />
            <Route path='single-booking/:id' element={<SingleBookingPage />} />
            <Route path='documents' element={<DocumentsPage />} />
            <Route path='my-account' element={<MyAccountPage />} />
            <Route path='reservation' element={<ReservationPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProtectedRoute` component should grab the current `location` object for the route being accessed and pass this in route state to the login route.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({
  isAllowed,
  redirectPath = "/sign-in",
  fromPath = null,
  children,
}) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  if (fromPath) dispatch(setURLPath(fromPath));


  if (!isAllowed) {
    return <Navigate to={fromPath} replace state={{ from: location }} />;
  }
  return children ? children : <Outlet />;
};
```

The login component should then access the passed route state and redirect *back* to the original route being accessed.

```
const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const login = () => {
  ...

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  navigate(from, { replace: true });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing some params (next_route) for example. and keep it along the process in signin so that when he finishes he can ge reredirected to the right place (next_route)